# Java voice recognition for very small dictionary

Tags: java, audio, voice-recognition

I have MP3 audio files that contain voicemails that are left by a computer.

The message content is always in same format and left by the same computer voice with only a slight variation in content:

"You sold 4 cars today" (where the 4 can be anything from 0 to 9).

I have be trying to set up Sphinx, but the out-of-the-box models did not work too good.

I then tried to write my own acoustic model and haven't had much better success yet (30% unrecognized is my best).

I am wondering if voice recognition might be overkill for this task since I have exactly ONE voice, an expected audio pattern and a very limited dictionary that would need to be recognized.

I have access to each of the ten sounds (spoken numbers) that I would need to search for in the message.

Is there a non-VR approach to finding sounds in an audio file (I can convert MP3 to another format if necessary).

**Update: My solution to this task follows**

After working with Nikolay directly, I learned that the answer to my original question is irrelevant since the desired results may be achieved (with 100% accuracy) using Sphinx4 and a JSGF grammar.

**1:** Since the speech in my audo files is very limited, I created a JSGF grammar (*salesreport.gram*) to describe it.  All of the information I needed to create the following grammar was available on this [JSpeech Grammar Format](http://www.w3.org/TR/jsgf/) page.

```
#JSGF V1.0;

grammar salesreport;

public <salesreport> = (<intro> | <sales> | <closing>)+;

<intro> = this is your automated automobile sales report;

<sales> = you sold <digit> cars today;

<closing> = thank you for using this system;

<digit> = zero | one | two | three | four | five | six | seven | eight | nine;
```

**NOTE:** Sphinx does not support *JSGF tags* in the grammar.  If necessary, a regular expression may be used to extract specific information (the *number of sales* in my case).

**2:** It is **very important** that your audio files are properly formatted.  The default sample rate for Sphinx is 16Khz (16Khz means there are 16000 samples collected every second).  I converted my MP3 audio files to WAV format using [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/).

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 1 -ar 16000 output.wav
```

Unfortunately, FFmpeg renders this solution OS dependent.  I am still looking for a way to convert the files using Java and will update this post if/when I find it.

Although it was not required to complete this task, I found [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) helpful for working with audio files.  It includes many utilities for working with the audio files (checking sample rate and bandwidth, file format conversion, etc).

**3:** Since telephone audio has a maximum bandwidth (the range of frequencies included in the audio) of 8kHz, I used the Sphinx [en-us-8khz](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/Acoustic%20and%20Language%20Models/US%20English%20Generic%20Acoustic%20Model/en-us-8khz.tar.gz/download) acoustic model.

**4:** I generated my dictionary, *salesreport.dic*, using [lmtool](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/tools/lmtool.html)

**5:** Using the files mentioned in the previous steps and the following code (modified version of Nikolay's example), my speech is recognized with 100% accuracy every time.

```
public String parseAudio(File voiceFile) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    String retVal = null;
    StringBuilder resultSB = new StringBuilder();

    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

    configuration.setAcousticModelPath("file:acoustic_models/en-us-8khz");
    configuration.setDictionaryPath("file:salesreport.dic");
    configuration.setGrammarPath("file:salesreportResources/")
    configuration.setGrammarName("salesreport");
    configuration.setUseGrammar(true);

    StreamSpeechRecognizer recognizer = new StreamSpeechRecognizer(configuration);
    try (InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(voiceFile))
    {
        recognizer.startRecognition(stream);

        SpeechResult result;

        while ((result = recognizer.getResult()) != null)
        {
            System.out.format("Hypothesis: %s\n", result.getHypothesis());
            resultSB.append(result.getHypothesis()
                    + " ");
        }

        recognizer.stopRecognition();
    }

    return resultSB.toString().trim();
}
```

Comment: Finding sounds in an audio file is what I'd call voice-recognition. Are we talking about avoiding the use of a specific algorithm?

Comment: Do you have influence on the system creating the soundfiles? Maybe it could be configured to put the number into the metadata (ID3-tags)?

Comment: ...or just use DTMF or some other simple encoding for the digits.

Comment: If the length of the spoken message is the same, you can drop start & end?

Comment: I do not have influence on the system.  The question is whether or not there is a way to find the sounds another way (perhaps by looking for byte patterns).  The message length varies since it takes longer for some words to be spoken than others (for example, the word SEVEN takes longer than the word TWO).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accuracy on such task must be 100%. Here is the code sample to use with the grammar:

```
public class TranscriberDemoGrammar {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Loading models...");

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

        configuration.setAcousticModelPath("file:en-us-8khz");
        configuration.setDictionaryPath("cmu07a.dic");
        configuration.setGrammarPath("file:./");
        configuration.setGrammarName("digits");
        configuration.setUseGrammar(true);

        StreamSpeechRecognizer recognizer =
            new StreamSpeechRecognizer(configuration);
        InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(new File("file.wav"));
        recognizer.startRecognition(stream);

        SpeechResult result;

        while ((result = recognizer.getResult()) != null) {

            System.out.format("Hypothesis: %s\n",
                              result.getHypothesis());
            }

        recognizer.stopRecognition();
    }
}
```

You also need to make sure that both sample rate and audio bandwidth matches the decoder configuration

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/faq#qwhat_is_sample_rate_and_how_does_it_affect_accuracy

Comment: After speaking with Nikolay directly, I was able to achieve 100% accuracy using Sphinx4.  I have edited the question to provide help for others looking to acomoplish the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Sphinx only work with WAVE file. For very limited vocabulary, Sphinx should generate good result when using a [JSGF](http://www.w3.org/TR/jsgf/) grammar file (but not that good in dictation mode). The main issue I found is that it does not provide confidence score (it is currently bugged). You might want to check three other alternative:

1. [SpeechRecognizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh361683%28v=office.14%29.aspx) from Windows platform. It provide easy to use recognition with confidence score and support grammar. This is C#, but you could build a native wrapper or custom server.
2. [Google Speech API](https://www.google.com/intl/fr/chrome/demos/speech.html) is an online speech recognition engine, free up to 50 request per day. There is several API for this, but I like [JARVIS](https://github.com/The-Shadow/java-speech-api). Be careful though, since there is no official support or documentation about this and Google might (and already have in the past) close this engine whenever they want. Of course, you will have some privacy issue (is it okay to send this audio data to a third party ?).
3. I recently came through [ISpeech](http://www.ispeech.org/) and got good result with it. It provides its own Java wrapper API, free for mobile app. Same privacy issue as Google API.

I myself choose to go with the first option and build a speech recognition service in a custom http server. I found it to be the most effective way to tackle speech recognition from Java until Sphinx scoring issue is fixed.

Comment: ortis, thanks for the suggestions.  I changed the correct answer to Nikolay's (see comments).